# Best way to combine C++ and C# projects which works both local and Azure DevOps?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, azure-devops

I Sometimes combine native C++ (not C++/CLI or C++/CX, just C++) and C# projects by means of P/Invoke.
I used to use such configuration:

1. Make C++ dll project. (ProjA)
2. Change target name of ProjA to `$(ProjectName)_d` only on Debug configuration.
3. Build ProjA once in Debug and Release - `$(SolutionDir)Release\ProjA.dll` and `$(SolutionDir)Debug\ProjA_d.dll` would be made.
4. Make C# project. (ProjB) Switch `dllName` of `DllImport` by using `#if DEBUG`.
5. Add `ProjA.dll` and `ProjA_d.dll` (and `*.pdb`) to ProjB as links.
6. Let ProjB to be built for x86 in configuration manager.
7. Add Build dependency.

Then everything worked well. ProjB detects changes in ProjA.

However, in Azure DevOps, it failed to build because `ProjA_d.dll` is not created in the Release build (step 3 is needed.)
I want to tell common way to do it if exists. or Do I have to write build event and make dummy files?

Comment: If both of the are .NET/CLI/CLR code, there is no need for P/Invoke. You can use any .NET dll in any .NET Project, regardless of original source language.

Comment: You can try adding three build tasks, one to build c++ project with debug configuration and one to build with release configuration, and the other one to build c# project in your build pipeline.

Comment: @Levi Lu-MSFT How can I build a single project?

Comment: Hi @v..snow please check below answer with screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add three build tasks in your build pipeline and configure each build task with the right project path and configurations, one to build c++ project with debug configuration and one to build with release configuration, and the other one to build c#. Please refer to below screenshot.

[image]

Configure each build task to your need. **Point the Project to the path of the specific project you want to build**. Please refer to below example.

[image]

**Solution**

```
# set env and vars

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'ProjA1/ProjA1.vcxproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: 'Debug'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'ProjA1/ProjA1.vcxproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
        xcopy /I /E /Y ProjA1\Debug Debug
        xcopy /I /E /Y ProjA1\Release Release

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'ProjA2/ProjA2.vcxproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: 'Debug'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'ProjA2/ProjA2.vcxproj'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: 'Release'


- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
        xcopy /I /E /Y ProjA2\Debug Debug
        xcopy /I /E /Y ProjA2\Release Release

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# tests
```

Comment: I used yaml and it requires "solution". I haven't known it it accept project.

Comment: Actually there are two dll projects and one depends on the another, say, ProjA1, ProjA2. So I wrote five tasks, but ProjA2 failed and said "cannot open file '../Debug/ProjA1_d.lib'". I inserted CmdLine task and tree `D:` but there are no `*.lib` and `*.dll`. Can you help me? EDIT: tree does not show files. I investigate more

Comment: Could you share your yml definition, and omit the sensitive information of your project.

Comment: I did! outputs are made in ProjA1/Debug so add task to xcopy then worked!

Comment: I want to show my yaml and accept this answer. How should I do in SO? Can I edit this answer?

Comment: Of course you can. You can click the 'edit' option at the bottom of above answer to edit. For yml, you can edit your question and copy and paste your yml and wrap it in ` `